# How to use checkboxes in a nested MenuItem

Tags: checkbox, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I want to create a checkbox which has three nested elements inside and each of these elements shall contain a list with checkboxes. My problem is that whenever the user clicks on one of the checkboxes, it doesn't get checked, but the menu gets closed.

Also, I can't figure out how to create a scrollbar inside one of the nested lists. At least not the proper way. My workaround was to wrap a Menu with the property maxHeight around the MenuItems, but I don't think that is the proper way. I tried nearly all props I can think of (menuListStyle, listStyle, nestedListStyle, ...), but nothing worked.

Here is my code with my last tries:

```
import React from 'react';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import ArrowDropRight from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation-arrow-drop-right';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';

const UserPermissionButton = () => (
<IconMenu
  iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
  anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
  targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
>
  <MenuItem
    primaryText="Permissions"
    rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
    menuItems={[
      <Checkbox label="Admin" />,
      <Divider />,
      <Checkbox label="Billing" />,
      <Checkbox label="Marketplace" />,
      <Checkbox label="Usercontrol" />,
    ]}
  />

  <MenuItem
    primaryText="Access Groups"
    rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
    style={{maxHeight: 150, overflow: 'auto'}}
    menuItems={[
     <MenuItem key={1} primaryText="Child 1" />,
     <MenuItem key={2} primaryText="Child 2" />,
     <MenuItem key={3} primaryText="Child 3" />,
     <MenuItem key={4} primaryText="Child 4" />,
     <MenuItem key={5} primaryText="Child 5" />,
     <MenuItem key={6} primaryText="Child 6" />,
     <MenuItem key={7} primaryText="Child 7" />,
     <MenuItem key={8} primaryText="Child 8" />,
    ]}
  />

  <MenuItem
    primaryText="Apps"
    rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
    menuItems={[
      <Menu maxHeight={200}>
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
        <Checkbox label="App" />
    </Menu>
    ]}
  />
</IconMenu>
);

export default UserPermissionButton;
```

**UPDATE:**

The code has changed to this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import ArrowDropRight from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation-arrow-drop-right';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';

class UserPermissionButton extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
      >
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Permissions"
          rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
          menuItems={[
            <Checkbox label="Admin" />,
            <Divider />,
            <Checkbox label="Billing" />,
            <Checkbox label="Marketplace" />,
            <Checkbox label="Usercontrol" />,
          ]}
        />

        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Access Groups"
          rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
          style={{maxHeight: 150, overflow: 'auto'}}
          menuItems={[
           <MenuItem key={1} primaryText="Child 1" />,
           <MenuItem key={2} primaryText="Child 2" />,
           <MenuItem key={3} primaryText="Child 3" />,
           <MenuItem key={4} primaryText="Child 4" />,
           <MenuItem key={5} primaryText="Child 5" />,
           <MenuItem key={6} primaryText="Child 6" />,
           <MenuItem key={7} primaryText="Child 7" />,
           <MenuItem key={8} primaryText="Child 8" />,
          ]}
        />

        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Apps"
          rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
          menuItems={[
            <Menu maxHeight={200}>
                {this.props.products.products.map(
                  product => <Checkbox key={product.id} label={product.name} />
                )}
          </Menu>
          ]}
        />
      </IconMenu>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({products}) {
  return {products}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserPermissionButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Basically, using `state`, you have complete control over when to show the `menuitems`.

```
<MenuItem
   onTouchTap={() => {
      this.setState({ menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen })
   }}
   primaryText="Permissions"
   rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
/>
{this.state.menuOpen ? (
  <Menu maxHeight={200}>
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
    <Checkbox label="App" />
  </Menu>): null}
```

In other words, your component will now have state as follows:

```
const UserPermissionButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    menuOpen: false
  },

  render () {
    <div>
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
      >
        <MenuItem
          primaryText="Permissions"
          rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
          onTouchTap={() => {
              this.setState({ menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen })
          }}
        />
      </IconMenu>
      {this.state.openMenu ? (
         <div>
            <Checkbox label="Admin" />,
            <Divider />,
            <Checkbox label="Billing" />,
            <Checkbox label="Marketplace" />,
            <Checkbox label="Usercontrol" />,
         </div>
      ): null}
    </div>
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the suggestion, but it doesn't quite work for me. I can't use getInitialState(), but changing this to
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false,
    };
  }
could work, but the main problem is that I have three menu Items and everyone of them has nested Items.

Comment: You can use this.state.menuOpen && (...) notation instead of this.state.menuOpen ? (...) : null